# Running a Python File from the Command Prompt

Tags: python, command-line

I'm trying to run a python file from the command prompt but I keep getting this error.

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I read the posts about placing `r` in front of your file path but my file does still not get executed.

```
C:\Users\jonko> python --version
Python 3.11.6

C:\Users\jonko>python3
Python 3.11.6 (tags/v3.11.6:8b6ee5b, Oct  2 2023, 14:57:12) [MSC v.1935 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> "C:\Users\jonko\OneDrive\Desktop\hello.py"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
     "C:\Users\jonko\OneDrive\Desktop\hello.py"
```

Comment: Use raw strings, which are prefixed with r or R, and don't treat backslashes as escape characters, then double up the backslashes to escape them or Use forward slashes instead of backslashes.

Comment: Type `python3 C:\Users\jonko\OneDrive\Desktop\hello.py` in one command, not first `python3` and then `C:\Users\jonko\OneDrive\Desktop\hello.py`.

Comment: @mkrieger1, I made a typo out of frustration. It's working!Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

At the command prompt `C:\Users\jonko>`, type `python3 C:\Users\jonko\OneDrive\Desktop\hello.py`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- If you are in the same directory as shown above, C:\Users\jonko, try `python3 OneDrive\Desktop\hello.py`
- Otherwise, change directory to the folder where your file is located and simply type `python3 hello.py`

Typing `python3` will open a Python shell where you can type and execute python code, so the only way for you to run `hello.py` inside it would be by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-do-i-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command/89243#89243) question, as an example.

Any errors that you see will be related to your `hello.py`, so you would need to add more information about your code and the errors thrown.